# Creating a new array from items in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects which is the result of a mongoDB query which shows the results of users' attempts at a quiz, it is assigned to a variable `res.locals.spellingTestResults`.  Each user can have multiple attempts.

```
[{
        _id: {
            user: {
                name: 'PageHill Class1 Child',
                userType: 'Child',
                email: '5ab79cc913840a359ff425f1@empty.com',
                __v: 0
            }
        },
        data: [{
                numberOfSpellings: 4,
                wrongAnswers: ['of', 'spellings'],
                rightAnswers: 2,
                score: 2
            },
            {
                numberOfSpellings: 4,
                wrongAnswers: ['spellings'],
                rightAnswers: 3,
                score: 3
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        _id: {
            user: {
                name: 'PageHillAdmin',
                userType: 'Teacher',
                email: 'jinky332@gmail.com',
                __v: 0
            }
        },
        data: [{
                numberOfSpellings: 4,
                wrongAnswers: ['first','spellings'],
                rightAnswers: 0,
                score: 3
            },
            {
                numberOfSpellings: 4,
                wrongAnswers: ['of', 'spellings'],
                rightAnswers: 0,
                score: 4
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

From this I would like to be able to create an array of objects (one for each user as in the above) containing a concatenation of each `wrongAnswers` array that belongs to them.  I would like to count the instances of each item in the resulting array.  The result wold look something like the below:

```
[{

    user: {
        name: 'PageHill Class1 Child'
    }

    wrongAnswers: {
        'spellings': 2,
        'of': 1
    },

    user: {
        name: 'PageHillAdmin'
    },
    wrongAnswers: {
        'spellings': 2,
        'first': 1,
        'of': 1
    }

}];
```

I do have some separate logic to combine all of the wrong answers across all of the users:

```
        let allWrongAnswers = [];
        res.locals.spellingTestResults.map(function(answers) {    
            answers.data.forEach(answer => {
                allWrongAnswers = allWrongAnswers.concat(answer.wrongAnswers);
            });
        });

        var countedSpellings = allWrongAnswers.reduce(function (allSpellings, spelling) { 
        if (spelling in allSpellings) {
            allSpellings[spelling]++;
        }
        else {
            allSpellings[spelling] = 1;
        }
        return allSpellings;
        }, {});
```

but I can't figure out how to combine and count the wrong answers for each user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one shot script:

```js
const dataFromMongo = [
  {
    _id: {
      user: {
        name: 'PageHill Class1 Child',
        userType: 'Child',
        email: '5ab79cc913840a359ff425f1@empty.com',
        __v: 0,
      },
    },
    data: [
      {
        numberOfSpellings: 4,
        wrongAnswers: ['of', 'spellings'],
        rightAnswers: 2,
        score: 2,
      },
      {
        numberOfSpellings: 4,
        wrongAnswers: ['spellings'],
        rightAnswers: 3,
        score: 3,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    _id: {
      user: {
        name: 'PageHillAdmin',
        userType: 'Teacher',
        email: 'jinky332@gmail.com',
        __v: 0,
      },
    },
    data: [
      {
        numberOfSpellings: 4,
        wrongAnswers: ['first', 'spellings'],
        rightAnswers: 0,
        score: 3,
      },
      {
        numberOfSpellings: 4,
        wrongAnswers: ['of', 'spellings'],
        rightAnswers: 0,
        score: 4,
      },
    ],
  },
];

const result = dataFromMongo.reduce(
  (acc, item) => [
    ...acc,
    {
      user: item._id.user.name,
      wrongAnswers: item.data
        .reduce((acc, item) => [...acc, ...item.wrongAnswers], [])
        .reduce((acc, wrongAnswer) => {
          return {
            ...acc,
            [wrongAnswer]: acc[wrongAnswer] ? acc[wrongAnswer] + 1 : 1,
          };
        }, {}),
    },
  ],
  []
);

console.log('result:', result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array of many things that you want to turn into one thing (user results => totals object), use array reduce: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Try defining the ideal object of counts with zero values as your initial value, then add to them in your reduce function.